# Why is this JUnit test case failing?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Everything seems perfect but the test case keeps failing, giving me a Java.lang.nullPointerException for all of these.

Here is the test case

```
@Test
    public void validMonths() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(1, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("January") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("February") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(3, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("March") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(4, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("April") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(5, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("May") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(6, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("June") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(7, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("July") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(8, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("August") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(9, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("September") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(10, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("October") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(11, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("November") == 0);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(12, 1, 1900);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("December") == 0);
    }
```

And here is my method

```
public String getMonthString(){
         String[] arrayOfMonths = new String[11];
         arrayOfMonths[0] = "January";
         arrayOfMonths[1] = "February";
         arrayOfMonths[2] = "March";
         arrayOfMonths[3] = "April";
         arrayOfMonths[4] = "May";
         arrayOfMonths[5] = "June";
         arrayOfMonths[6] = "July";
         arrayOfMonths[7] = "August";
         arrayOfMonths[8] = "September";
         arrayOfMonths[9] = "October";
         arrayOfMonths[10] = "November";
         arrayOfMonths[11] = "December";
         if (this.myMonth > 0 && this.myMonth <=12){
             return arrayOfMonths[this.myMonth-1];
         }
         else{
             return "NO_VALUE";
         }
     }
```

does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted stack trace and indicated what line was throwing the exception.

Comment: This line is the failure trace, assertTrue(dow.getMonthString().compareTo("January") == 0);

Comment: Either dow is null, dow.getMonthString() is null, or compareTo() is throwing the NPE. Print out dow and dow.getMonthString().

Comment: unrelated to your exception, but you should use assertEquals("expectedString", dow.getMonthString())

Comment: What is this.myMonth type?

Comment: Post your DayOfWeek class

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818181/java-class-failing-a-lot-of-junit-tests-not-sure-why

Answer (score 1):

arrayOfMonths needs to be size 12, not 11.

EDIT: Whoever upvoted me shouldn't have. :-) That would throw and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, not an NPE. It's still a real problem, just not the one he's having.

Comment: Still failing after I changed that